# How to transfer photos to x-www-form-urlencoded immediately after taking a picture EXPO

Tags: react-native, expo, image-uploading, react-native-camera, x-www-form-urlencoded

I want to take a picture, save it to an album and send the image right away.
(**Do not select from album.**)

There is no problem in taking the current picture, saving it in an album and checking the uri.

but the **x-www-form-urlencoded** sending process does not work properly.

**I think there may be a problem with the format of sending the API.**

postman is also attached. (No problem in Postman.)

```
 takePictureAndCreateAlbum = async () => {
    const { uri } = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
    console.log('uri', uri);
    const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);
    console.log('asset', asset);

    const filename = asset.filename;

    MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Expo', asset)

      // POST API
      .then(() => {

        var file = new FormData();
        file.append({file: uri});

        return fetch(/* API_URL */, { 
              method: 'POST',
              headers:{

                  'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                  'Accept': 'application/json'
             } , body : file} )

         .then((response) => response.text())
              .then((responseData) => {
                  console.log(responseData);
              })
              .done();

      })
      .catch(error => {
        Alert.alert('An Error Occurred!')
      });
  };
```

[Postman Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBvO0.png)

[Postman Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAtmu.png)

Answer (score 0):

When appending to a `FormData` instance, the first parameter is the field name (What your server will be getting as an object key for this file), the second one is an object in the following form:

```
{
  uri: // The uri you received from the camera,
  type: // The file type (i.e.: image/png),
  name: // The file name
}
```

In your case, it would be like this:

```
// Split the uri by `.` (periods)
const uriParts = uri.split('.');
// Grab the file type at the end of the uri
const fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];

file.append('picture', {
  uri,
  type: `image/${fileType}`,
  name: 'FILE-NAME.${fileType}`
});
```

Also, when sending files, your `Content-Type` header should be `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @bongjuri1551 Please share the code you have with my suggestions.

Comment: var file = new FormData();
        const uriParts = uri.split('.');
        const fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];
        file.append('picture', {
          uri,
          type: `image/${fileType}`,
          name: `FILE-NAME.${fileType}`
        });

Comment: fetch(`http://52.231.70.40/api/file/uploadReceipt/${ids.id}/${ids.loginId}`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          },
          body: file
        })

         .then((response) => response.text())
              .then((responseData) => {
                  console.log(responseData);

                  console.log('file',file)
              })
              .done();

      })

Comment: error is 400, Required request part 'file' is not present @Nick Rameau

Comment: @bongjuri1551 Sorry, didn't mean for you to post it in the comments, but to update your question with it.